# Почему срабатывает событие onchange у элемента input [type=file] если файл не был выбран?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, события, angular4

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  eventProccess(event: any) {
    console.log('eventProccess is called');
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="eventProccess($event)"/>
```

---

1. Запускаю приложение.

   [image: скриншот]
2. Нажимаю «Выберите файл» - (в появившемся диалоговом окне, не выбирая никакого файла) - нажимаю «Отмена» - (в консоле ничего не отобразилось). Т.е. как я понял, если файл не был выбран то событие `onchange` у `input` не срабатывает.
3. Далее: снова «Выберите файл» - Отмечаю файл - «Открыть» - и да: в
   консоле отображается «eventProccess is called». Т.е. сейчас событие
   `onchange` сработало и соответствующий обработчик был вызван.
4. Но что происходит далее: нажимаю опять «Выберите файлы» - (не
   выбираю ничего) - «Отмена» - в консоле повторилось «eventProccess is
   called». Т.е. на этот раз событие `onchange` почему-то сработало хоть я и не выбирал файл в диалоговом окне. **Почему так происходит?**
5. Дальше еще интереснее: если я еще раз повторю шаг 4 - «Выберите
   файлы» - (не выбираю ничего) - «Отмена» - в консоле ничего не появилось.

Comment: Отмена убирает выбранный файл из инпута, и это всё-таки является изменением :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996578/4928642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `input type='file'` cобытие `onСhange` проходит каждый раз когда меняется значение свойства `files`.

- На первом шаге `files = [];`
- На втором шаге у вас оно не изменилось.
  События нет.
- На третьем `files` стал содержать один элемент.
  `[selectedFile]`. Вызов события.
- На четвертом снова стал пустым `[]`.
  Снова событие.
- На пятом изменений нет, массив пустой. Нет события.